# set environment variable in ruby and pass it to shell

Tags: ruby, bash, sinatra

I am running a sinatra web app that gets a file (upload) from the user. It then transfers the file to a server via scp. Can I grab the filename from the params Hash and set it as an environment variable and pass it to the scp command. Below is a snippet of my code.

```
ENV[file] = params['arne_site_file'][:filename]
transfer = `scp -i /opt/zabbix-proxy/etc/.ssh/id_rsa $file zabbix@X.X.X.X:/home/zabbix/ARNE_5216_files`
```

Params Hash is -

```
{
"arne_site_file" => {
    :filename => "ARNE_SITE__BB5216_L16B_936441_HWY_54_A.xml"
},
        "submit" => "Validate File"
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution. It turns out I was missing quotes. ENV['file'] = params['arne_site_file'][:filename]. This resolved the issue. Great to know that env variables can be set by Ruby for other bash scripts to access.

Comment: You should also quote the expansion in the command `"$file"`, to allow for all valid filenames.

Comment: A better solution, though, is to use something like `Kernel.spawn` which lets you pass arguments directly instead of relying on the shell to supply arguments from its environment.

Comment: It's 2023 and I have just been caught out by this for the entire day, you really helped me here, thanks!